# DSC PowerSeries alarm panel

Tags: security, alarm

I have a DSC PowerSeries alarm pad and the display is now hard to read.

Is it possible to just replace the display screen or how hard would it be to upgrade the keypad with a digital touchscreen type if possible.

[image: Picture of display screen]

Comment: Where does it get its electrical power? Is there cabling behind it?

Comment: many touch screens don't work well with cold, gloved, or wet hands; I wouldn't want to deal with that while trying to deactivate an alarm...

Comment: If it's battery powered, try changing the batteries. It might suddenly be bright and easy to read again.

Comment: The company would probably be the best ones to about any replacement or addon parts that work with it.  Have you cleaned the screen?  Find reading glasses help with small stuff.

Comment: Figure out what your alarm system that it's attached to is, and whether you own it or you rent it from your alarm company. When you know what it is, you'll know what control panels it can support, and you can buy one of those if you own it, or request one if you rent it. Or you can buy a whole new system that supports the display you want.

Comment: I own the system and have monitoring through monitoring center. I will check what ones are compatible with their system.. there is power plug through the wall that powers it but ive also had to change the internal battery previously

Comment: I have recently installed a DSC 1832, which has several different model keypads.  I don't recognize yours.  What model DSC system do you have, and which keypad do you have?
Wired keypads are powered by the wires from the system, and there is a brightness control.  If you have a wireless keypad, there may be similar controls.

Answer (score -1):

### Aim a spotlight at it

The new paradigm in alarm systems is "wireless".  The alarm modules are using the airwaves to communicate, and as a result they require *very* little power.

It's now possible to have sensors and master controller that run entirely on batteries, and this greatly simplifies installation and eliminates a bunch of electrical code issues that drive installation costs to the moon.

However, making it work on "battery" requires the master controller take VERY low power.  This controls the type of display it is possible for the unit to have.  What you want is an illuminating display that makes its own light, so it's readable in the dark. Making light takes a lot of energy, and that's just not possible on the energy budget available to the unit. Its only option is an LCD display, which requires almost no power but relies on ambient light, *the way a book does*.

So your best bet is to improve the lighting around the unit so the LCD display is more readable.

Even if you had the *rather considerable* electronics "chops" to replace it with an illuminating display, the labor would still be hundreds of hours just to get all the details right, to say nothing of having to change the battery twice a week.